# How to draw clean lines with a graphics tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet

I am learning to use a graphics tablet with display for drawing. I currently have the problem that it is hard to draw clean lines.

Straight lines are doable with some concentration, but, for example, drawing a smooth arc seems to be very hard. I wonder if there are any tricks or techniques one can learn, if it is a matter of practice or if skilled artists just draw and erase parts of the line again and again until each part of the curve is smooth.

I often have some jitter in the line that is (probably) not a technical problem but the larger problem is that I just don't get the steepness of the curve right on the tablet, but need to correct it over and over again until it is smooth.

Comment: what kind of tablet do you use? Just wondering because some tablets use like flow settings for your pen and if they are set too high or low can cause jitteriness when drawing lines. you might be able to achieve a smoother flow in your curves by playing with some of these settings if you have them.

Comment: another tip sometimes It helps to make 2 layers one called rough and one called fine roughly draw your curves and edges and then go to the fine layer and draw overtop your rough edges to more finely adjust using your rough as a reference on where your jittery lines are.

Comment: @sketcherskt It's a XP-PEN Artist 12 pro tablet. Currently I first make a sketch with for example a 40px pen and then try to get a smooth curve that roughly matches the sketch with for example a 3-5px pen using hard pens to get anime style outlines. I think there may be some helpful features in graphics programs as well. As a beginner I am a bit overwhelmed by the available brushes in krita (what I am currently using). I am currently using the "fineliner" brush to draw anime style outlines.

Answer (score 3):

Just practice and proper posture.

Arcs are typically drawn from the wrist for small ones. Then either the elbow or shoulder for larger ones. The more you try and draw arcs with the fingers, the harder it becomes to keep them smooth. Same basic principle as drawing on paper.

The folly many novice tablet users make is to use a tablet like it's a mouse.... plant the wrist and then make small short, finger movements much of the time. The smaller the tablet, the more common this behavior seems to be. That's not always what you want.

Comment: Would it be considered very unprofessional to use just a tiny bit of *Smoothing* when drawing in Photoshop? Like 10%.